# javascript clearTimeout isn't working from a child page

Tags: javascript

These are the relavent lines.

```
// In the parent page I set the timer and attach its handle to the window
window.warnTo = window.setTimeout("WarnTimeout();", 20000);

// If I clear the timer in the same page it works great
window.clearTimeout(window.warnTO);

// In the child page launched with window.open, 
// I try to clear the timer and the timer still fires
window.opener.clearTimeout(window.opener.warnTO);
```

All variables appear to be set and window.opener appears to be the parent window.
I'm stumped.

Comment: Usually, you shouldn't use a string argument for `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, though in this case, it seems ok.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to access the page using the opener property?

```
window.opener.clearTimeout(window.opener.warnTO);
```

Here's my sample code for testing this. I use Interval rather than Timeout to give a clearer indication of it working:

**Opener.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){ window.open("opened.html");}
  window.x = setInterval("bla()",500);
}

function bla()
{
  var obj  = document.getElementById('output')
  obj.innerHTML += "Bla";
}
</script>

<div id="output"></div>

<button id="button">Open the new window</button>
```

**Opened.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.opener.clearInterval(window.opener.x);
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

As you pointed out in the comments, you've also got a typo in the code sample you've provided.

Change `warnTO` to `warnTo`.

Comment: He must have updated his question after I'd writen this answer.

Comment: window.opener.location is the URL in the parent window so it looks ok.

Comment: Does this solution work for you George? I've tested this and it works for me.

Comment: I think it's because of a typo. Duh. warnTo and warnTO.

Comment: That would do it too. I'll update to include that. I think you should change your question back to how it was so it's less confusing.

Comment: Your original question had window.clearTimeout in the code which then chaned to window.opener.clearTimeout. At least that's as I recall the original question.

Comment: My point there is window.clearTimeout worked on the SAME page but failed on the child page where it has to be window.opener.clearTimeout. The target of window.opener.clearTimeout is where the problem was. Does that make sense?